# Yii2, Assets. Base css in the end

Tags: yii2, adminlte, asset-management

Simple question I've got after work with AdminLTE design. There are all assets (css) ends with AdminLTE.min.css, it means that even select2.css goes first...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/select2/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
```

They did wrong, because now all data in rewritten\hovered from AdminLTE.min.css, yes it's easy way for html code but not for developer. So, question...

We need register bundle with css on each page always as "last", so it was rendered last (for example after kartik select2 asset, or another bundle we use somewhere on page\code). Any solution for this?

Thank you...

ADDED:
We have css\html\js AdminLTE and Select2 Bundle from kartik, so now I'm searching solution for this one. As you can see select2 css loaded before main css (AdminLTE.min.css). So I want use kartik Select2 Bundle, but only where it's needed, and of course do not load it on EVERY page - only where it's needed. I know how Asset::register($this) works, and know its parameters... But maybe I miss something, can it do Yii2 at all?

Comment: AdminLTE styles Select2 so it should be added after. Is this budle you need to register last yours?